# Skip failed installation of package and install alternative with pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

Let's say I got a `requirements.txt` which contains the following dependencies:

```
git+ssh://git@mygithost.de/my_project_group/package_a.git

alabaster==0.7.11
Babel==2.6.0
...
xlrd==1.1.0
pytest
pytest-cov
```

Installing this dependencies works fine on my machine with company proxy, as I got a VPN tunnel that allows me to connect to `mygithost.de`.

Others at my workplace, do not have the allowance to use this git repository and therefore the installation fails right at the first package.
So we are planing to host the packages which we depend on on a seperate SVN-Server where everyone here has access to.

Now to my actual question. We don't want to take care of 2 separate requirement files whereof one points to git and one points to the svn repo.

Is there any way, to prevent pip from failing if it does not find a certain package and install an alternate package instead?

Somehow like (in pseudocode):

```
try install this:
    git+ssh://git@mygithost.de/my_project_group/package_a.git
if it fails install this instead:
    svn+http://.....

alabaster==0.7.11
Babel==2.6.0
...
xlrd==1.1.0
pytest
pytest-cov
```

Comment: For context: what is the reason you yourself want to use the local repository, and not the general repository?

Comment: The dependency I talk about is not a local git repository on my machine but hosted on a gitlab instance which is not accessible from all machines but only the ones having the vpn tunnel installed. The ones that don't have access to gitlab should instead install the same package from a svn server which everyone got access to. (The package there is a exact copy of a release on our git server)

Comment: Since you say that everyone has access to the SVN, why not use that all the time?

Comment: That was not what I'm asking: why can't you use the general repository?

Comment: Because git is our standard versioning tool. Some more information to that somehow weird setup. We have machines from our company and some of the client company. The client has setup a proxy, that only allows us to access our svn but not our git from their machines. There is unfortunately no option of getting the client to let us pass the proxy to our gitserver on all devices due to their company policy. So to sum up: our companies devices have no issue accessing either git or svn. Their machines (except a couple of special ones with vpn tunnel) can only access our svn.

Comment: Anyhow the question is not about if this is some kind of a weird setup but more about the feasibility of installing from another repo via requirements.txt without maintaining a second seperate requirements file.

Comment: Well, I think the question is somewhat about the weird setup. For example, why can't you directly work on the SVN repository yourself? With the current way you're doing this, you have to maintain the same package at two places (which I think is harder than working with two requirements files). *Or* you have a development (git) and release (svn) version, but then you should always pull from the release version anyway for testing other packages that use this package.

Comment: The svn repo would only be used for already finished releases. So to say just file system, which could be use from pip from a remote machine. So yes, the development of the packages is on git and svn would only be used as "storage" for a copy of every Release. So no need of maintaining the svn repository. There will be no changes at all in svn after a copy of a release was pushed to the svn repository.